# C++ Data Validation Issue

Tags: c++

```
if (month > 0 && month <= 12)
    if (day > 0 && day <= checkDays(month, year))
        if (year >= 1752 || year <= 9999)
            if((month != 12 && day != 31 && year != 9999))
                return true;
            else return false;
        else return false;
    else return false;
else return false;
```

I have the values month = 12, days = 31, and year = 2008 and the data validation is failing at the last part, but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: WHat does `checkDays` do? Can we see it's code?

Comment: `if((month != 12 && day != 31` - There's a double false.

Comment: Hate those && ... ! expressions!

Comment: What do you mean by a double false?

Comment: also I think you want `year >= 1752 && year <= 9999` rather than `year >= 1752 || year <= 9999` (the latter is always true).

Answer (score 2):

Your first year condition uses OR when you wanted AND; your second year condition is exactly inverted from what I suspect you wanted.

You also have an order-of-operations bug: you can't check the day until *after* you validate the month and the year (assuming what `checkDays` does is provide the maximum day number for a particular (month, year) pair; if so, you should rename it `days_in_month`).

Finally, code like this is generally much easier to read if written as a series of if-fail-return-false conditions without any nesting.  Like so:

```
// Year range supported is [1752, 9999].
// (Gregorian calendar introduced in 1752 in Great Britain.)
if (year < 1752 || year > 9999)
  return false;

// Valid month numbers in [1, 12].
if (month < 1 || month > 12)
  return false;

// Valid day numbers in [1, n] where n depends on month and year.
if (day < 1 || day > checkDays(month, year))
  return false;

// 9999-12-31 is invalid (used as a sentinel value?)
if (year == 9999 && month == 12 && day == 31)
  return false;

return true;
```

By the way, the [Long Now](http://longnow.org/) people would like a word regarding your upper year limit.

Answer (score 2):

I find it's nearly always easier to write these things with the "find the false things and return". So:

```
if (month < 1 || month > 12) return false;
if (day < 1 || day > 31) return false;
if (year < 1752 || year > 9999) return false; 
if (month == 12 && day == 31 && year == 9999) return false;

// If we get here, everything is fine, so return true.
return true;
```

Of course, you should probably check the `day` based on which month it is:

```
int daysInMonth[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
if (month < 1 || month > 12) return false;  // Must do this before checking day!
int daysThisMonth = daysInMonth[month]; 
// Check for leapyear.
if (month == 2 && year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0))
{
   daysThisMonth = 29;
}
if (month != 2 && day < 1 || day > daysThisMonth) return false;
...
```

Comment: `"you should probably check the day based on which month it is"` - that's probably what `checkDays` was for in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of speculation, since I don't quite know what your function is supposed to do, but here goes.

`month != 12 && day != 31 && year != 9999` only returns true if the month is not 12 **and** the day is not 31 **and** the year is not 9999.

So for your input, it's:

```
month != 12 && day != 31 && year != 9999
=> false && false && true
=> false
```

Don't you maybe want:

```
month != 12 || day != 31 || year != 9999
```

Which will return true if either the month is not 12 **or** the day is not 31 **or** the year is not 9999.

An equivalent, but possibly more understandable way of writing it:

```
!(month == 12 && day == 31 && year == 9999)
```

So that's "if the month is 12 and the day 31 and the year 9999, return false".

Comment: I need it so that it doesn't allow the date 12/31/9999 to come in.

Comment: @user2311799 That's what `month != 12 || day != 31 || year != 9999` will do.